# display + sign from the query string url using php

Tags: php, url, request, query-string

Im trying to send a query string in url

for ex : `url : localhost/myfile.php?number=8777,+9822,+9883`

in myfile.php when i give echo the query string :

```
echo $_REQUEST['number'];
```

output :

```
 8777,9822,9883
```

but the expected output is :

```
8777,+9822,+9883
```

How can i display + sign also.

**UPDATE :**

actually that url is web request from the android/ios device app,

im providing webservice in php,

so android/ios developers are sending request with a querystring contains `+ sign`

so how can i handle this situation?

Comment: use the urlencode function to send such value

Comment: url encode your url.`localhost/myfile.php?number=8777,%2B9822,%2B9883`

Comment: You have failed to understand HTTP. Punch out and go home.

Comment: please check my update in question

Answer (score 2):

```
+ is reserved. PHP is correct in translating an unencoded + sign to a space.
```

You can use urlencode() urldecode() for this.
The + must be submitted in PHP as the encoded value: %2B

Answer (score 0):

You should then use `urlencode()` function to create that url:

```
<?php

var_dump($_GET['number']);

echo 'http://localhost/myfile.php?number='.urlencode('8777,+9822,+9883');
```

**EDIT**

If this is url that you receiving and cannot do anything with that you can use for example:

```
echo substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'=')+1);
```

and you will get

> 8777,+9822,+9883

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i dont know what you're trying to do, but here's a suggestion

// where base64_encode('8777,+9822,+9883') = ODc3NywrOTgyMiwrOTg4Mw

localhost/myfile.php?number=ODc3NywrOTgyMiwrOTg4Mw

// on myfile.php

`echo base64_decode($_REQUEST['number']);`

// this will output -> 8777,+9822,+9883

UPDATE ---------------------------
if you have no other choice , you can use this

```
<?php
// get URL query string
$params = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 

// if you have $params = www.mydomain.com/myfile.php?number=9988,+9876,+8768
$temp = explode('=', $params);
echo $temp[1] .'<hr>';


// if you have $params = www.mydomain.com/myfile.php?number=9988,+9876,+8768&number2=123,+456,+789
$params2 = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 
$temp3 = explode('&', $params2);
foreach($temp3 as $val){
    $temp4 = explode('=', $val);
    // # // $GET = $temp4[0]; // if you need the GET VALUES
    $VALUE = $temp4[1];
    echo $VALUE .'<br>';
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.... :)

Comment: basically what the moto is : from an android/ios app, im getting a webrequest : like www.mydomain.com/myfile.php?number=9988,+9876,+8768 so i need to get all the numbers including +sign